# Mysql Trigger query with join other table

Tags: mysql, triggers

i have the necessity of create a Trigger to save the record (obtained with a JOIN with another table) in audit table before that your values are updated.

I not know well the triggers, but i created this.

Is possible make it work?

Error reported is:

```
#1415 - Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger
```

*the table on which i applied a trigger is DESKTOP and I obtain a Name and Surname fields of relative record with a join on table Users or conversely.

```
DELIMITER //

    CREATE TRIGGER desktop_befUpd
    BEFORE UPDATE
       ON desktop FOR EACH ROW

    BEGIN

        SELECT
        Name,Surname,id
        FROM
        users
        JOIN
        (
        SELECT ID,IDAIFA,brand,model,id_users FROM desktop
        ) dev ON users.id = dev.id_users;

       -- Insert record into audit table
       INSERT INTO data_history
       ( IDAIFA,
         dt_datetime,
         Name,
        Surname
       )
       VALUES
       ( dev.IDAIFA,
         NOW(),
         users.Name,
       users.Surname );

    END; //

    DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You can usually get such things to work with a single `INSERT INTO... SELECT` query; but triggers are very finicky on referencing the table the trigger is attached to within the trigger, so having the subquery with `desktop` might cause issues. If you are trying to "log" the previous values, using `OLD.[fieldname]` and `NEW.[fieldname]` are more likely what you should be using.

Comment: @Uueerdo it *will* cause issues, specifically the "Mutating Table" problem. David-88, can you post the ***complete*** record layout for ***both*** tables please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your select in its current form likely returns a lot of rows, this is my best guess as to what you need/are trying to do:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER desktop_befUpd
BEFORE UPDATE ON desktop FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO data_history (IDAIFA, dt_datetime, Name, Surname)
   SELECT OLD.IDAIFA, now(), u.name, u.surname
   FROM users AS u 
   WHERE u.id = OLD.id_users
   ;

END //

DELIMITER ;
```